# SPO 2013 permissions: contribute level not working in unique permission site

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, unique

Permissions structure:

Subsite A with unique permissions

Subsite B of that site A inherits permissions

User with contribute, approve, or edit permissions set at site A cannot upload files to library

Full control users can

It seems like the _layouts/upload.aspx function isn't accessible to less than full control users.

I don't want to grant full control in this scenario so how this is best resolved? And why does it happen in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

To upload a document it doesn`t require Full control access and permissions you are having works. I would like to know is there any permissions broken at a library level. Can you confirm before I do further analysis?

Thanks,
Venkat Konjeti

Comment: No, the library inherits its site permissions which inherits the "unique" permissions of subsite A.